# My audio is there but how can I get back my video?

Tags: rendering, movie-clip-editor

This *was* displaying my video and playing the accompanied audio track.
However somehow I tried moving some windows around, and now I get this, a blank video with perfect audio.

Is there any way to discover where my video is hiding and synchronize it to the audio once again?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your preview window is displaying a histogram (technical reference image). Click on the checkerboard icon at the bottom of the VSE timeline

[image: vse display icon]